# Parse Nested array to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy

I'm using pyarrow to read data from ORC and PARQUET format and then my target is to convert this nested array of data to JSON format. Below is the snippet that i'm using to read data and convert it to DataFrame

```
if storage_type == "orc":
    data = orc.ORCFile(file_name).read().to_pandas()
elif storage_type == "parq":
    data = parquet.read_table(file_name).to_pandas()
```

but while using `json.dumps()` i noticed the nested arrays are not being encoded properly to json format.
Below is the **TARGET** format that i'm trying to achieve. Note i have multiple nested arrays like `contact`, `phone` and `hours`

```
  {
    "XXXX_code": "XXXX",
    "website": "https://www.randomwebsite.com",
    "brand": "XXXXXX",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "XXXXXXcode": "XXXXXX",
        "phone_number": "XXXXXX5054",
        "firstname": "XXXXXX",
        "code": "01016",
        "lastname": "XXXXXX",
        "title": "XXXXXX New York)",
        "source": "XXXXXX_Apr2016.xlsx",
        "source_date": "2016-04-19",
        "type": "FOM",
        "email": "scott.vanarsdale@XXXXXX"
      },
      {
        "XXXXXXcode": "1031",
        "phone_number": "609-XXXXXX",
        "firstname": "XXXXXX",
        "code": "01016",
        "lastname": "XXXXXX",
        "title": "Sr. DOM XXXXXX",
        "source": "XXXXXX.xlsx",
        "source_date": "2016-04-19",
        "type": "DOM",
        "email": "craig.salera@XXXXXX"
      }
    ],
    "lon": "-70.XXXXXX",
    "phone": [
      {
        "phone_number": "207-XXXXXX",
        "source": "XXXXXXWebServices",
        "type": "XXXXXX",
        "source_date": "2022-12-12",
        "code": "XXXXXX"
      }
    ],
    "email": "",
    "hours": [
      {
        "monday": "",
        "code": "01016",
        "tuesday": "",
        "friday": "",
        "wednesday": "",
        "thursday": "",
        "hours": "Monday-Friday: 09:00-19:00;Saturday: 09:00-18:00;Sunday: Closed",
        "source": "CoreXXXXXX",
        "sunday": "",
        "source_date": "2022-12-12",
        "type": "sales",
        "saturday": ""
      },
      {
        "monday": "",
        "code": "XXXXXX",
        "tuesday": "",
        "friday": "",
        "wednesday": "",
        "thursday": "",
        "hours": "Monday-Thursday: 07:30-18:00;Friday: 07:30-17:30;Saturday: 08:00-16:00;Sunday: Closed",
        "source": "CoreXXXXXX",
        "sunday": "",
        "source_date": "2022-12-12",
        "type": "service",
        "saturday": ""
      }
    ],
    "source": "BIRT"
  }
```

while this is what i'm able to achieve until now. I'm unable to decode nested arrays to proper JSON format

`res1 = json.dumps([{K:V for K,V in tup} for tup in data['json']])`

Result

```
{
        "hours": "[{saturday=09:00 AM - 07:00 PM}]",
        "website": "https://www.randomwebsite.com",
        "address": "[{zip=XXXXX, code=3903}]",
        "code": "XXXX",
        "lon": "-117.79XXXXX",
        "source": "XXXX",
        "phone": "[{phone_number=714-XXX-XXXX}, {phone_number=714-XXX-XXXX}]",
        "XXX_code": "XXXX",
        "geography": "[{area=LAN}]",
        "name": "TUSTIN",
        "source_contact": "XZZZ",
        "programs": "[{code=12334}]",
        "id": "",
        "employees": "[{firstname=Ramon}]",
        "fax": "714-XXXXXX",
        "brand": "XXXXX",
        "lat": "33.7XXXXXX",
        "email": null,
        "contacts": "[{Firstname=XXXXX]",
        "source_date": "2023-04-29"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your variable `data` is just a Pandas dataframe, why not just use `data.to_json()` function. You will want to set the orient value as appropriate and described in the [pandas to_json docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: I did try this but doesn't work out. The nested array turns out to be String type and Key,Value pair inside it separated by "="

Comment: You need to post your original data to have help then.